# How do I fix "Failed to build DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision" for a dependency that has been uninstalled?

Tags: node.js, react-native

```
Failed to build DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: react-native-vector-icons
  Paths: /Users/collumj/research/kishar-nine/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/__fixtures__/files/package.json collides with /Users/collumj/research/kishar-nine/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/kisharNine.app/package.json

This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
Error: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: react-native-vector-icons
  Paths: /Users/collumj/research/kishar-nine/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/__fixtures__/files/package.json collides with /Users/collumj/research/kishar-nine/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/kisharNine.app/package.json
```

I had `react-native-vector-icons` installed (and working) a couple of days ago. Had an issue with a debugger line not being hit so I thought maybe restarting the packager would help. Now the packager won't start at all. I have:

- removed `node_modules` and reinstalled
- checked out code from a prior commit (that didn't have react-native-vector-icons) and removed `node_modules` etc.
- `./node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh clean`
- `react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons`
- `watchman watch-del-all`
- `rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf ios/build/ModuleCache/* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && npm i --silent`

Still getting the same error. I can checkout a fresh copy of the repo and start it with no issues so I have to assume this is a caching/build issue.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: you might simply have missed the [npm prune](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune) step, which prunes that global cache.

Comment: No change. Added prune to the `rm -rf $TMPDIR ... ` line, didn't change anything.

Comment: Make sure that this package is not included twice in all files, where you are supposed to add it as a dependency (like `android/settings.gradle`, `MainApplication.java`, etc).

Comment: Well the solution seems to have been to delete my ios and android folders and reset to my last checkin. Something got built wrong? Anyway, put that in an answer to the question and I'll mark it Solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of error may occur if the package you are trying to add to the project is included twice, so the build system fails to register a package with a duplicate name. It may happen when you run link command several times.

To fix it make sure that all files, that are usually modified after running `react-native link` (for example `android/settings.gradle`, `android/app/build.gradle`, etc) have only one entry for the package you are trying to add. To be safe, you could even try to revert changes under `android/` and `ios/` directories and run link again.

Comment: The weird thing: this only happened (and happened twice) when I added a `debugger` line to the `render` function in a component in a library. Can't imagine why, but that's the sequence of events.